# bash parameter-expansion: removing multiple occurences of the same character

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

It's GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).
I have variable with text in it. For example:

```
var="this is     a variable   with some text     :)"
```

now I want to have `var2` having the same content but multiple spaces replaced with singe one. 
I know we can do it with sed, tr, awk and hundred other ways... but is there a chance to do it with parameter-expansion which bash performs ? 
 Tried:

```
var=${var/  / } # replacing 2 spaces with 1, but not much helps
var=${var/[ ]*/ } # this replaces space and whatever follows.... bad idea
var=${var/*( )/}  # found this in man bash, whatever it does it still doesnt help me...
```

`var2=$(echo $var)` with hope that echo solves problem - doesnt do the job bcs it doesnt preserve special characters like tab and so on..

I strongly would like to have it solved with something that `man bash` offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*( )` is an *extended* glob, which needs to be enabled using `shopt -s extglob` before you can use it to match zero or more spaces.

The correct replacement, though, would be to replace *one* or more spaces (`+( )`) with a single space. You also need to use `${var// ...}` to replace *every* occurrence of multiple spaces, not just the first one.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "$var"
this is     a variable   with some text     :)
$ echo "${var//+( )/ }"
this is a variable with some text :)
```